# Beamer handout: removing colours

Tags: beamer, color

I'm using beamer for my presentation where I use a lot of colours to point out certain terms in equations with

```
{\color<2->[rgb]{1.0,0.22,0} some text}
```

When I make the handout, the colours will all appear together on one slide.

Is there a way to say to ignore all the colours in handout?

I could remove them all, but my presentation is quit long. I wondered if there was a systematic way.

Comment: This is a lot easier if the colours themselves are defined in the preamble: do you have most of the use cases as a hard-coded colour (as in the example) or as a logical/named one?

Comment: @JosephWright No I'm afraid I always did the code as in the example... It started as a try-out and then I got stuck on that. In the future I'll be smarter ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your colours are hard-coded then the best you can do is to redefine `\color` to do nothing in handout mode.

```
\mode<handout>{%
  \def\color<#1>[#2]#3{}
}
```

This is risky as it assumes all uses have both the `<...>` and `[...]` arguments: a more sophisticated approach is possible. I'd *strongly* recommend giving each colour a name, as you can then do

```
\definecolor{my-colour-1}{rgb}{1.0,0.22,0}
\mode<handout>{%
  \definecolor{my-colour-1}{RGB}{0,0,0}
}
```

which will turn the colour into black in handout mode without any internal fiddling.

Comment: Perfect! And that's indeed way better. Luckily I only used the color with <...> and [...]. I cannot upvote but thanks!